# Can't deserialize my POJO sent from an Angular http post request on my Springboot POST mapped function

Tags: java, json, angular, spring-boot, jackson

For context, my app is a coffee shop and I want to sent a an array of items over to my springboot backend. However jackson gives the exception:

```
Cannot construct instance of `me.andrewq.coffeeshop.menu_items.Menu` 
(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value 
(no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: 
java.util.ArrayList[0])] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Cannot construct instance of `me.andrewq.coffeeshop.menu_items.Menu` 
(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value 
(no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: 
java.util.ArrayList[0]).
```

This is what the item's class looks like (after omitting the setters and getters):

```
public class Menu {

    private int productId;

    private String name;

    private double price;

    private String[][] productOptions;

    private String type;

    // These 3 variables belong to drinks. The creams and sugars more so for coffees
    private String currentSize;

    private Integer creams;

    private Integer sugars;


    public Menu(int productId, String name, double price, String productOptions, String type){
        this.productId = productId;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.productOptions = convertOptions(productOptions);
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Used for converting the product options which is a key-value pair seperated by a ',' in the DB, into a 2D array in this class.
     * @param options
     * @return
     */
    private String[][] convertOptions(String options) {
        String[] optionPairs = options.split(",");

        //hard coded b/c I know that these are pairs 
        String retVal[][] = new String[optionPairs.length][2];

        for(int i = 0; i < optionPairs.length; ++i){
            String[] temp = optionPairs[i].split(":");
            retVal[i] =  temp;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return String.format("{productId: %i, name: %s}", this.productId, this.name);
    }

}
```

The request is received in a controller class as:

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping(path = "/guestOrder")
    public String order(@RequestBody List<Menu> order){
        
        for(Menu item: order){
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }
        
        return "Sending order worked";
    }
}
```

In Angular the item is defined as:

```
export interface Menu {
    productId: number;

    name: string;
    
    price: number;
    
    productOptions: string[][];
    
    type: string;

    // additional field for drinks and coffees
    currentSize: string;

    creams: number;

    sugars: number;
}
```

And the http request call is:  `` this.http.post<string>(`${this.url}/guestOrder`, this.orderItems); `` where `http: HttpClient` and `orderItems: Menu[]`.

Without formatting the JSON, error occurs at column 65 of the JSON string:

```
[{"productId":1,"name":"Iced Coffee","price":2,"productOptions":[["S","2.00"],["M","2.50"],["L","3.00"]],"type":"IC","currentSize":"S","creams":0,"sugars":0}]
```

This is at the first bracket of `productOptions`

Comment: Are you sure that this is the precise JSON string that is being passed? The exception you mention says that it wants to parse the `productOptions` element as a String instead of an array, which is not reflected in the JSON that you give. Also, it says something about line 1, column 65, but there is no column 65 on line 1, which makes debugging even harder (maybe you have formatted the JSON? If so, pls give the raw unformatted text).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had formatted the text for readability before posting here but I inserted in the actual line of JSON that was in the body at the bottom of the post. Apparently the error occured at the first opening bracket "[" of the productOptions attribute.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In this case the JSON matches the position from the error message, but still does not explain why it wants to parse a String where it should parse an array. The JSON looks fine to me, and seems to match your POJO. Is it possible that you had the `productOptions` in your Java code as a plain String (instead of `String[][]`) in an earlier version and have not recompiled or redeployed correctly?

Comment: I ran ```mvn clean``` and then ```mvn spring-boot:run``` and the error has actually changed to something in relation to not being able create the ```Menu``` object. I will edit in the next exception into the post.

Comment: Thanks, for the new input - now it's actually much easier than the first time :-) Also pls fix your formatting of the post - you must have messed up the closing formatting tags when editing. It was pretty fine the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception actually says it pretty well - you need to add a default constructor to your POJO class.

The JSON parser works by first creating an empty instance and then calling the setter method for each property in encounters in the JSON text. A property that is not contained in the JSON remains untouched and therefore has the value that the default constructor assigns to it (usually `null` unless you set it to something else).

I hope the are getters and setters that you say are omitted for clarity, are indeed there, otherwise it won't work as well.